# Regular expression equivalent to following automaton?

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions, finite-automata

Having a little trouble wrapping my head around this one.

What is a regular expression equivalent to the following automaton?

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. First consider the automaton obtained by replacing the two transitions labelled by $\{a,b\}$ by transitions labelled by $c$:
[image]

Find a regular expression for this new automaton and then replace $c$ by $\{a,b\}$ in the result.